# How to delete the oldest file if the number of files exceeds 5 using Windows script?

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

i am looking for a windows script that will delete the oldest file placed there if the number of file exceeds 5

could you please help if such solution exists?

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code by editing your question...

Answer (score 1):

This will preserve the most recently modified 5 files in the current directory, deleting all the rest

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=5 eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /b /a-d /o-d *') do del "%%F"
```

It works by using DIR to list out all files sorted by last-modified date, descending. The list is processed by FOR /F, skipping the first 5 lines.

Comment: How could this be adapted to zip files?

Comment: @Chris - This answer cannot be adapted to delete all but the 5 most recently modified files in a zip file.